# Android how to drag imageview in relativelayout and then bring it back to place

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-imageview, touch-event

I'm trying to make an imageview draggable using onTouchListener. This is the code i have so far for the drag

```
switch (ME.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN://IF USER PRESSED ON THE IMAGE

        origix = v.getLeft();   //save original x coordinate calculated with the offset
        origiy = v.getTop();
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE://IF USER IS MOVING THE IMAGE


            System.out.println("MOVED");
            int x_cord = (int)ME.getRawX(); //get coordinate of the user touch
            int y_cord = (int)ME.getRawY(); 

            //set the image to the new coordinates based on where the user is touching and dragging
            MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());   
            marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - origix, y_cord - origiy,0, 0);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);  
            MOVED = true;   //mark that the image has been move

    break;
```

The variable 'v' is the imageview. The issue im getting is that the getRawX and getRawY isnt returning the correct coordinates (i think...). When i try touch the image and then try to drag it, the image starts dragging from another position. Usually much higher and little more to the right than the original position. The imageview is in a RelativeLayout and i'm using API 10

Comment: hi have a look at this sample http://androidrox.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/android-sample-app-drag-and-drop-image-using-touch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to get the offset of the relativelayout and the screen

```
int offsety = (screenheight - relheight); //screenheight is the height of the screen and rel height is the height of the relativelayout that the image is in then changed     
marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - origix, y_cord - origiy,0, 0); to this     
marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - (v.getWidth()/2), y_cord - offsety - (v.getHeight()/2),0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

When the move starts, you need to initialize an offset (i.e. `x_offset` and `y_offset`) with the initial position of the `ImageView`.

Then, the move should be modified as follows:

```
marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - x_offset, y_cord - y_offset,0, 0);
```

This will stop your drag from starting from a different position than your `ImageView` starts from.

Comment: I just tried that and updated my code above but I'm still getting the same issue. The images are starting to move from a different position than when I didnt put in the offsets but its still starting from a different positio than the original position

Comment: You need a `break;` after the block of code for `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: o sry i was deleting a large amount of comments between the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE that I deleted the break; as well. I updated my code

Comment: needed to get the offset of the relativelayout and the screen

    int offsety = (screenheight - relheight); //screenheight is the height of the screen and rel height is the height of the relativelayout that the image is in


then changed 
    marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - origix, y_cord - origiy,0, 0);

to this

    marginParams.setMargins(x_cord - (v.getWidth()/2), y_cord - offsety - (v.getHeight()/2),0, 0);


Thanks David Manpearl! I wouldn't have thought of the offsetting without your help